# GN Language Failing on Absolute Path

Tags: c++, webrtc, chromium, ninja, gn

I'm trying to build some ninja files using google's GN.  However, I get thrown invalid token errors no matter how I reference the file.

```
   rtc_executable("python_server") {
  testonly = true
  include_dirs = ["/C:/"]
  sources = [
    "python_wrappers/main.cc",
    "/C:/test.h",
  ]
  deps = [
    "..:webrtc_common",
    "../rtc_base:rtc_base_approved",
    "../rtc_base:stringutils",
    "../rtc_tools:command_line_parser",
  ]
  if (!build_with_chromium && is_clang) {
    # Suppress warnings from the Chromium Clang plugin (bugs.webrtc.org/163).
    suppressed_configs += [ "//build/config/clang:find_bad_constructs" ]
  }
}
```

According to the documentation it says I can use system absolute names and relative names:

[Link to Docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/+/HEAD/docs/language.md#File-and-directory-names)

However, no matter how I link it -- it seems to not recognize the file. Any help on how to use external dependencies with GN would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the relevant error message and what token is it referring to?

Comment: Link to docs was stale. Updated link: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/+/48062805e19b4697c5fbd926dc649c78b6aaa138/docs/language.md#File-and-directory-names